# SQL Server 2017 - JOOQ code generation with Gradle

Tags: sql-server, gradle, jooq

I'm coming from the MySQL world and code generation using JOOQ has always been an easy task. The output would nicely fit into my target package name. Now I have this project where I need to use an SQL Server 2017 as the main database. I bought a JOOQ license and managed to set up Gradle to work with it. Flyway works like a charm but for some reason I'm stuck on JOOQ code generation process.

I know in MySQL schemas and tables are pretty much the same thing, but not in SQL Server. All my tables are using DBO as their default schema and are located at the root of my Tables directory in the database.

Now the problem. When I run generateJooqSchemaSource JOOQ will start code generation for all tables in the database, including [master] and [msdb], even though I specified my database name in the connection URL. The code generation process should only target my specified database.

Any idea how to fix this?

Here is my gradle build file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:7.0.0.jre8'
        }
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'idea'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.6.RELEASE'
    id 'nu.studer.jooq' version '3.0.2'
    id 'org.flywaydb.flyway' version '5.1.4'
}

group 'org.test.security'
version '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.1.2.RELEASE'
    }
}

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'

    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:5.2.4'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:4.0.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.0.1'

    implementation 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:7.0.0.jre8'
    implementation 'org.firebirdsql.jdbc:jaybird-jdk17:3.0.5'

    implementation 'org.jooq.pro:jooq:3.11.9'
    implementation 'org.jooq.pro:jooq-meta:3.11.9'
    implementation 'org.jooq.pro:jooq-codegen:3.11.9'

    compileOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'

    jooqRuntime 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:7.0.0.jre8'
    jooqRuntime 'org.firebirdsql.jdbc:jaybird-jdk17:3.0.5'

    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

jooq {
    version = '3.11.9'
    edition = 'PRO'
    master(sourceSets.main) {
        jdbc {
            driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
            url = "jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=MyDatabase"
            user = "sa"
            password = "admin123"
        }
        generator {
            database {
                name = "org.jooq.meta.sqlserver.SQLServerDatabase"
                inputSchema = "dbo"
            }
            generate {
                relations = true
                deprecated = false
                records = true
                immutablePojos = true
                fluentSetters = true
            }
            target {
                packageName = 'org.test.security.database.master'
                directory = 'target/generated-src'
            }
        }
    }
}

flyway {
    url = "jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=MyDatabase"
    user = "sa"
    password = "admin123"
    table = "Schema_History"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, jOOQ will generate code for all catalogs (databases) and all schemas. If you want to limit code generation to only one database, you need to specify the inputCatalog, possibly along with the inputSchema. Some details can be found [on this page](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-catalog-and-schema-mapping)

In other words, write

```
database {
    name = "org.jooq.meta.sqlserver.SQLServerDatabase"
    inputCatalog = "my_database_here"
    inputSchema = "dbo"
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It makes much more sense now.